# How to get unique values from a string without removing the delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have to remove duplicate values from a string,in which child values are separated by a delimiter. My sample string is like `"aa~*yt~*cc~*aa"`  where ~* is the delimiter and need to remove duplcate occurence of aa

I Tried using set cmmand and below code also, but they are giving output as

```
"a~*ytc"
```

However I need the output :

```
"aa~*yt~*cc"
```

```
d = {}
s="aa~*yt~*cc~*aa"
res=[]
for c in s:
    if c not in d:
      res.append(c)
      d[c]=1
print ("".join(res))
```

I have gone through many answers provided,  but could not able to solve this. Please let me if there is any  solution to it. Thanks and really appreciate your time :)

Comment: but "aa" is not duplicate to "*aa" according to your logic (looking at your code)

Comment: What about the asterisk? at the moment we have `aa` and `*aa`.

Comment: This code doesn't treat `~` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

You could [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) the string by the separator, take the `set` of the resulting `list` (to remove duplicates), sort the elements according to the order of appearance in the original string and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) setting again `~` as a delimiter:

```
s = "aa~*yt~*cc~aa"

'~'.join(sorted(set(s.split('~')), key=s.index))
# 'aa~*yt~*cc'
```

---

If performance is important, define the dictionary used to sort the resulting set beforehand:

```
l = s.split('~')
length = len(l)
d = {j:length-i for i,j in enumerate(l[::-1])}
# {'aa': 1, '*cc': 3, '*yt': 2}
'~'.join(sorted(set(l), key=lambda x: d[x]))
# 'aa~*yt~*cc'
```

Comment: sorted([...], key=s.index) is an interesting solution, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Is the order of the substrings relevant?

if order is not important:

```
print("~".join(set("aa~*yt~*cc~aa".split("~"))))
```

if the order is important:

```
#f7 function source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/11971785
def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

print("~".join(f7("aa~*yt~*cc~aa".split("~"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` with `re.findall`:

```
import re
d = "aa~*yt~*cc~aa" 
new_d = re.findall('\w+|[\W]', d)
r, c = [a for i, a in enumerate(new_d) if a.isalpha() and a not in new_d[:i]], iter([i for i in new_d if not i.isalpha()])
result = ''.join(f'{a}{next(c)}{next(c)}' if i < len(r) - 1 else a for i, a in enumerate(r))
```

Output:

```
'aa~*yt~*cc'
```

With `re.findall`, the delimiter characters do not need to be known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One common way to ensure uniqueness while maintaining order (in all Python variants) uses a `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict as OD

s = "aa~*yt~*cc~aa"
sep = "~"

uinq = sep.join(OD.fromkeys(s.split(sep)))
# 'aa~*yt~*cc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
>>> s="aa~*yt~*cc~aa"
>>> s_list=s.split("~")
>>> s_final = "~".join([s_list[i] for i in range(len(s_list)) if s_list[0:i].count(s_list[i])==0])
>>> s_final
'aa~*yt~*cc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since python 3.7 dicts are ordered, so you can use them

```
>>> '~'.join(dict.fromkeys("aa~yt~cc~aa".split('~')).keys())
'aa~yt~cc'
```

for other python versions you can use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758708/7851254

However, i wouldn't recommend to use such unobvious feature. You can stick to some other answer, just choose one that is understandable from first look